# How many people saw Christ Jesus rise from the dead?

Tags: life-of-jesus, history, 1-corinthians, resurrection-of-jesus

Initially, I did a Google search, but I wasn't happy.  I wonder if you guys know if the Bible specifies how many people witness the resurrection of Christ Jesus.

By witness I mean, a person that saw Christ Jesus alive after his death. I would like to know because it is hard to call them *false witness*. Like in this scripture.

> Yea, we are found false witnesses of God; because we witnessed of God
>   that he raised up Christ: whom he raised not up, if so be that the
>   dead are not raised. (‭1 Corinthians‬ ‭15‬:‭15‬ ASV)

If the Bible doesn't say, can you tell me a ballpark number based on the scriptures?

[ Side Note ]
I know Christ Jesus was in a sealed tomb and man did not see the actual resurrection take place. As if mankind was found unworthy. Anyway, I wonder how big is that group of witnesses.

Comment: Quick answer none the Roman guards were asleep according to what the Sanhedrin told the Guards to say, even though sleeping while on guard duty was punishable by death.

Comment: [This was found in about 10 seconds on a google search.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurrection_appearances_of_Jesus)

Comment: I saw the link but it doesn't say how many. 30+ ?

Comment: Do you mean how many witnessed the event, or how many saw him afterward?

Comment: The verse is grossly out of context, by the way. Paul is speaking *hypothetically* there, saying *if* Jesus did not rise from the dead or *if* we will not be raised, then all of us (Christians) are liars. Read the rest of 1 Corinthians 15; he gives a partial list of people who saw the risen Lord.

Comment: It's literally 10 verses before the verse you quoted.

Comment: There's the story of the 500 plus the apostles and a few others. I'd say about 530.

Comment: I invite you to consider the difference between the words *rise* and *raise*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the whole chapter. Earlier in 1st Corinthians 15 the Bible's definitive answer to this question is given.

> For I delivered to you as of first importance what I also received: that Christ died for our sins in accordance with the Scriptures, that he was buried, that he was raised on the third day in accordance with the Scriptures, and that he appeared to Cephas, then to the twelve. Then he appeared to more than five hundred brothers at one time, most of whom are still alive, though some have fallen asleep. Then he appeared to James, then to all the apostles.

So according to the Bible the answer is `> 500`. A couple dozen of these are listed by name both here and in the resurrection accounts in the Gospels, the rest are unnamed but it is specifically noted that the same people are not being counted over and over as the "more than five hundred" figure is specifically noted as "at one time", so there was at least one appearance before a bit of a crowd.

Answer (score 3):

The writer of this letter is not saying that we are false witnesses, he is saying that the Corinthians and other believers don't fully understand what happened when Jesus died and was resurrected.

Jesus Himself conquered death, so it isn't so much that Jesus was raised, but that Jesus rose after defeating death.

---

The other thing is that no one saw Him rising from the grave, they saw Him after He rose from the grave.

Someone saying they saw God raise Jesus from the grave is obviously not telling the truth, because that is not written in the Bible, I think that would for sure be in there and not be left out.